# Count the most clicked video in a website

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, html

In my asp.net website I have several videos and I want to store the click count on each video in to a database for the purpose of getting the most clicked(viewed) video in the website. Can any one help me how can we done this.
here is my html

```
<div class="row">
                <video id="video1" controls width="100%">
                <source src="<%=mp4 %>" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="<%=ogv %>" type="video/ogg">
                <source src="<%=webm %>" type="video/webm">
                Your browser does not support HTML5 video. </video>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

You would listen to the play-event on your video-element, and do the logging from there.

```
var video = document.getElementById('video1');
video.play = function(e) {
  //do your logging here, for example an ajax post
};
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#event-media-play